# nested_inner_scroll disabled mouse wheel scrolling with Flutter Web

Tags: flutter-web

I have been trying to achieve a design in Flutter that requires nested scrolling. And I came across this package called [nested_inner_scroll](https://pub.dev/packages/nested_inner_scroll). This package implements my design very well, however, it disabled the mouse wheel scrolling at the same time. I had to scroll through my Flutter web app by manually dragging the side scroll bar.

I figured out it could be because of the required `coordinator` variable for the outer and inner scroll.

If anyone is familiar with this package, it would be highly appreciated if you can guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this widget as your parent widget

```
ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(dragDevices: {
              PointerDeviceKind.touch,
              PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
            }), child: yourWidget() )
```

Comment: I'm using a CustomScrollView for my whole program body, so I will have to wrap everything within this widget?

Comment: Yes, exactly.. you use the `ScrollConfiguration()` as a parent  CustomScrollView .
Note that you must import `import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart'` for `PointerDeviceKind`

Comment: I see, but still, it doesn't override the package behaviors. I somehow found an alternative solution using NestedScrollView class. Appreciate your help a lot though!